# Calling prop.test function in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate several binomial proportion confidence intervals. My data are in a data frame, and though I can successfully extract the `estimate` from the object returned by `prop.test`, the `conf.int` variable seems to be null when run on the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

cases <- c(50000, 1000, 10, 2343242)
population <- c(100000000, 500000000, 100000, 200000000)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(cases, population))
df %>% mutate(rate = prop.test(cases, population, conf.level=0.95)$estimate)
```

This appropriately returns

```
    cases population       rate
1   50000      1e+08 0.00050000
2    1000      5e+08 0.00000200
3      10      1e+05 0.00010000
4 2343242      2e+08 0.01171621
```

However, when I run

```
df %>% mutate(confint.lower= prop.test(cases, pop, conf.level=0.95)$conf.int[1])
```

I sadly get

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `confint.lower` is of unsupported type NULL
```

Any thoughts? I know alternative ways to calculate the binomial proportion confidence interval, but I would really like to learn how to use `dplyr` well.

Thank you!

Comment: @akrun my apologies -- vestigial evidence of real data vs my attempt to share a reproducible chunk. I edited the code. Thanks.

Comment: What is `sumcases`? :)

Comment: if we dig into the help page for `?prop.test` in the `Value` section the description for `conf.int` tells us "a confidence interval for the true proportion if there is one group, or for the difference in proportions if there are 2 groups and p is not given, or NULL otherwise" so you need to test either one or two groups to generate a non`NULL` value for you `conf.int`, not the 4 groups that are currently being tested

Comment: @SeGa so sorry, shouldn't have tried to do a hasty edit of variable names just before pasting. sumcases=cases. Post edited. thank you.

Comment: @Nate I saw that, but I thought that `dplyr` would be doing a sort of row-wise call of `prop.test` and thus the rows would each be considered individually, and the first part of your quoted section ("a confidence interval for the true proportion if there is one group") would apply. Am I misunderstanding `dplyr`?

Comment: Try `library(purrr) ; library(dplyr) ; df %>% mutate(confint.lower = map2(.x = cases, .y = population, .f = ~ prop.test(.x, .y, conf.level=0.95)$conf.int[1]))`.  I haven't really dug into the htest class to figure out why your version isn't working, but this should.  EDIT: Actually, on quick reflection, it's probably not working because `prop.test` isn't vectorized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::rowwise()` to group on rows:

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(lower_ci = prop.test(cases, pop, conf.level=0.95)$conf.int[1])
```

By default `dplyr` takes the column names and treats them like vectors. So vectorized functions, like @Jake Fisher mentioned above, just work without `rowwise()` added.

This is what I would do to catch all of the confidence interval components at once:

```
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(tst = list(broom::tidy(prop.test(cases, pop, conf.level=0.95)))) %>%
    tidyr::unnest(tst)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much Nate and @JakeFisher . Thanks for providing both an explanation as well as helpful code -- much appreciated.

Comment: Very clean code that works perfectly well, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.0.0, [`rowwise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html) is no longer being questioned.

As of version 0.8.3 of `dplyr`, the lifecycle status of the `rowwise()` function is "questioning".

As an alternative, I would rather recommend the use of `purrr::map2()` to achieve the goal:

```
df %>%
  mutate(rate = map2(cases, pop, ~ prop.test(.x, .y, conf.level=0.95) %>%
                                     broom::tidy())) %>%
  unnest(rate)
```