# Working with tidyverse, ggplot, and broom to add confidence interval to a proportion test (prop.test) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, categorical-data, broom

Let's say I'm working with proportions, I have two main variables (sex and pain_level). It's not difficult to plot them:

[image: Plot 1 - proportions]

With tidyverse and broom (and thanks for this link here: [Calling prop.test function in R with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977337/calling-prop-test-function-in-r-with-dplyr)) I can compare if the proportions are statistically different.

[image: Proportion test]

Now comes the question!

I want to add to the plot, the error bar. I know it's not as difficult as I'm thinking, but I could not find a way to do it. I've tried to replicate this link here (http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/achoulde/94842/labs/lab07_solution.html) but I'm trying to stay at tidyverse environment.

The desired output should be something like that:
[image: Desired output]

Please feel free to use the script/syntax below that simulate the original dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame(sex = rep(c("M","F"), 18),
                 pain_level = c("High","Moderate","low"))

#plot
ds %>% 
  group_by(pain_level, sex) %>% 
  summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = sex, fill = pain_level, y = prop)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary") +
  facet_wrap( ~ pain_level) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

#p values of proportion test

ds %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  group_by(pain_level, sex) %>% 
  summarise(cases = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pop = sum(cases)) %>% #compute totals
  distinct(., pain_level, .keep_all= TRUE) %>% #keep only one value of the row 
  mutate(tst = list(broom::tidy(prop.test(cases, pop, conf.level=0.95)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(tst)
```

Comment: I can't get your code to run without errors. `tipo` is a variable that is missing. Generally, `geom_errorbar()` would do the trick with `ymin = conf.low` and `ymax = conf.high` from the `prop.test`s.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The variable name is pain_level (instead of tipo). Could you please try to emulate it now ? I've tried ymin and max but did not have success. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following might roughly resemble your desired output:

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(pain_level, sex) %>% 
  summarise(cases = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pop = sum(cases)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(tst = list(broom::tidy(prop.test(cases, pop, conf.level=0.95)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(tst) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sex, estimate, group = pain_level)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = pain_level)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  facet_wrap(~ pain_level)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Amazing. I didn't know it was simple as that. I always see the "conf.low" and "conf.high" as results that we need to compute before plotting. Good to know it's automatically computed by ggplot.

Comment: They are not computed by ggplot but by the `prop.test()` function that is called just before handing the data to ggplot.

Comment: ahhh, okay! Now it is clear to me! Thanks again, I upvoted and accepted your answer.